# Flutter - Exclude unwanted platform specific dependencies

Tags: flutter, configuration, multiplatform

I am new to Flutter.
I am experimenting with the framework and I would like to explore multiplatform apps.
I am specifically targeting:

- Windows
- Macos
- Linux

For each platform I'm using their own theme and icon sets (e.g. fluent & fluent_icons on Windows, adwaita & adwaita_icons on linux, cupertino & macos_ui on mac,...). However, even though the design is different across different platforms, I am sharing the component's behaviour by leveraging MVVM and platform-agnostic components.

I've been reading through all the flutter docs of [packages vs plugins](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)
, however I think that either I didn't get something or there is something I'm missing.

When I perform a platform-specific build I would like to get rid of all the unnecessary dependencies (e.g. cupertino on Windows). How can I achieve this?
I was thinking about creating:

- A "shared" package for business logic (ViewModels, shared components, ...)
- A package for each individual platform that will depend on "shared"

With this approach, I can have separate `pubspec.yaml` for each individual platform and, therefore, I can include only the needed dependencies.

```
my_app
  - my_app_linux // Only support for Linux with Adwaita widgets
    - linux 
    - lib
    - pubspec.yaml
  - my_app_windows // Only support for Windows with Fluent widgets
    - windows 
    - lib
    - pubspec.yaml
  - my_app_macos // Only support for Macos with MacOs widgets
    - macos 
    - lib
    - pubspec.yaml
  - my_app_shared (here I can just actually use the root project's "/lib" folder)
    - lib
    - pubspec.yaml
```

Have you got any advice/experience? Did I miss something in the official documentation of package vs plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, this is not possible without any workaround. Take a look at following GitHub issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23122#issuecomment-927938161

In essence, you can create platform-specific widgets and inject those widgets during compile time by passing an environment variable with `--dart-define`.

## Example

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const bool MACOS_PLATFORM = bool.fromEnvironment("MACOS_PLATFORM", defaultValue: false);
  static const bool LINUX_PLATFORM = bool.fromEnvironment("LINUX_PLATFORM", defaultValue: false);
  static const bool WINDOWS_PLATFORM = bool.fromEnvironment("WINDOWS_PLATFORM", defaultValue: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Important note about tree shaking:
    /// For this to work you have to make a direct constructor call or a static function call e.g. MacOSWidget()
    ///
    /// This will NOT work:
    /// 
    ///     MacOSWidget macOSWidget;
    ///     if (MACOS_PLATFORM) return macOSWidget;

    if (MACOS_PLATFORM) return MacOSWidget();
    else if (LINUX_PLATFORM) return LinuxWidget();
    else if (WINDOWS_PLATFORM) return WindowsWidget();
    else return MyDefaultWidget();
  }
}
```

And then run your app with `flutter run my_app --dart-define MACOS_PLATFORM=true` or build it with `flutter build my_app --dart-define MACOS_PLATFORM=true`.

Do **NOT** forget to include the argument `--dart-define <desired_platform>=true`. Otherwise, the environment variable is not exposed at compile time and tree shaking will not work.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code that demonstrates the structure you've described:

```
my_app
  - my_app_linux
    - linux 
    - lib
    - pubspec.yaml
  - my_app_windows
    - windows 
    - lib
    - pubspec.yaml
  - my_app_macos
    - macos 
    - lib
    - pubspec.yaml
  - my_app_shared
    - lib
    - pubspec.yaml
```

Your approach of using separate packages for each platform and a shared package for business logic is a good way to achieve your goal. By structuring your project this way, you can have platform-specific dependencies in each platform package's `pubspec.yaml` and only include the necessary dependencies for each platform.

Just ensure that you properly manage the dependencies and imports across your different packages. You can use the shared package for platform-agnostic components and logic, and then customize the platform-specific behavior by implementing the required UI components and dependencies in the individual platform packages.